# Return retrieved value from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an application which uses Firebase as the data store. We are using Tier Pattern to separate our Business Logic(and data access logic) from the User Interface. This is what we were doing in other projects with other data stores.

As an example we want to read data from Firebase that is then set in a class called `Stimmungsabfrage`. Then we want to work with this data and to present it also in our controllers(textviews, listviews) in an activity (in our UI).

In our data access class we are using the following function to retrieve the data:

```
root.child(strKey).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
 for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
   // Hier bekommst du dann letztlich die Stimmungsabfrage
   StimmungAbfrage stimmungAbfrage = child.getValue(StimmungAbfrage.class);
   }
}})
```

The problem with this function is that it does return `void`. So we are not able to return the retrieved object `stimmungAbfrage` to the user interface.

The only way is to assign the user interface controls right in this function, which we want to avoid, because we want to separate the UI from the data access logic.

How can this be done in Firebase?

Comment: I think there is no way to do this other than from inside `onDataChange`. If you want to separate the code, maybe you can call function from inside it and place that function on you UI section, or use something like [event bus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Answer (score 0):

Remove for loop:

```
for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){}
```

Simply write:

```
StimmungAbfrage stimmungAbfrage = child.getValue(StimmungAbfrage.class);
```

It will not return void.

Comment: The function onData does return void. It makes no difference if I use a loop or not. The function is not able to return a value

Comment: can you explain the structure of parent link of stimmungAbfrage. @Mo Prog

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the case. Here is the link to the function: https://gist.github.com/MbProg/df09c7fd24b94be52a74a3369da75ede. I have commented it on line 23. I would like to return the retrieved value from firebase and not implement the UI stuff in that function because this function belongs to the Data Access logic and I want to seperate it from the UI. But onDataChange does return void and so I cannot return any retrieved value from Firebase and have to implement the UI stuff in this function which I want to avoid

Comment: It looks like you are using old Firebase version, please use the new version of Firebase Google. It is more developer friendly. Here is the link for Firebase Google: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: I have in my app/build.gradle: compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1' and that is the last and I have a project installed in Firebase. How can I get sure that I have the latest version installed. I could not find  out from the document. And does the latest version change the way it reads from the database? Because in the Firebase Assistant in my Android studio there is still just the realtime database, which keeps the problem I have explained above